# regex for name with capital letters in Xcode

Tags: regex, xcode

I am trying to change all names that looks like this: `thisForExample` and change it with: `this_for_example` in Xcode with regex. Does anyone know how to do that?

I have tried with this: `([a-z][A-Z])*[a-z]?`
but it does not find anything.

Comment: This quickly fails as soon as you have to deal with names like someURL, URLString, someURLString, which are fairly common. See my answer for why regex is the wrong hammer for this. (and for an improved universal PCRE regex for your particular and simple case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Perl** would be a good tool for this (if you insist on using Regex)as it **supports case modification** in substitution patterns:

- `\l` => change **first char** (of following match variable) to lower case
- `\L` => change **all chars** (of following match variable) to lower case
- `\u` => change **single char** (of following match variable) to upper case
- `\U` => change **all chars** (of following match variable) to upper case

If all you care is to **convert (simple/trivial!) variables and method names** à la `thisForExample` into `this_for_example`.
For this a single regex like this would be sufficient:

```
echo 'thisForExample = orThisForExample();' \
| perl -pe 's/(?<=[^A-Z])([A-Z]+)(?=[^A-Z])/_\L\1/g;'
//output: "this_for_example = or_this_for_example();"
```

As soon however as you're expecting to come across (quite common) names like…

```
fooURL = URLString + URL + someURLFunction();
```

…you're in trouble. **Deep trouble**.

Let's see what our expression does with it:

```
echo 'fooURL = URLString + URL + someURLFunction();' \
| perl -pe 's/(?<=[^A-Z])([A-Z]+)(?=[^A-Z])/_\L\1/g;'
//output: "foo_url = _urlstring + _url + some_urlfunction();"
```

Pretty bad, huh?

And to make things even worse:
It is **syntactically impossible to distinguish** between a (quite common) **variable name** "URLString" and a **class name** "NSString".

**Conclusion**: **Regex** alone is pretty **hack-ish and error prone** for this kind of task. And simply **unsufficient**. And you don't want a single shell call to potentially **mess up your entire code base**, do you?
There is a reason why Xcode has a **refactor tool** that utilizes clang's grammar tree to differentiate between syntactically identical (pattern-wise at least) variable and class names.
This is a problem for **context free languages**, not **regular languages**. Hence **regular expressions cannot deal with it**. You'd need a contect free grammar to generate a language tree, etc. (and at that time **you've just started building a compiler**)

Also: Why use under_scores anyway? If you're using Xcode then you're probably coding in ObjC(++) or similar anyway, where it's common sense to use camelCase. I and probably pretty much **everybody** else **would hate you** for making us one day deal with your underscored ObjC/C/… code.

---

**Alternative Answer:**

In a comment answer to Paul R you said you were basically **merging two projects, one with under_scored naming, one with camelCased naming**.
I'd advise you then to **switch your under_scored code base to camelCase**. For two reasons:

1. Turning under_scored names into camelCased is way less error prone then vice versa. (That is: in a camelCase dominated environment only, of course! it would be just as error prone if you'd mainly deal with under_scored code in Xcode. Think of it as "there's simply less code to potentially break" ;) )
2. Quoting my own answer:

> […] I and probably pretty much
>   **everybody** else **would hate you** for making us one day deal with your
>   underscored ObjC/C/… code. […]

Here is a simple regex for converting under_score to camelCase:

```
echo 'this_for_example = _leading_under_score + or_this_for_example();' \
| perl -pe 's/(?<=[\w])_([\w])/\u\1/g;'
//output: "thisForExample = _leadingUnderScore + orThisForExample();"
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to find `[a-z][A-Z][a-z]`.

Automating the replacement process will be tricky though - how do you plan on changing an arbitrary upper case letter to its lower case equivalent ?

Comment: Also: why mess with existing naming conventions?

Comment: I have not thought that far:)

Comment: because I am adding two projects together and I want to use the same name convention

Comment: You'll probably need to write some kind of script to do this, using e.g. Perl.

Comment: @MeMi/PaulR: You'll find a Perl shell command in my answer (using case modifiers for convenience) along with why I wouldn't use regex for this. Also @Memi: If you're merging under_scored and camelCased (supposedly ObjC) code, then what the hell made you go for under_score? O_o *shudder* Whatever, my answer also mentions a under_score->camelCase regex shell command. (use at own risk as regex alone is the wrong tool for this, imho)

Answer (score 0):

Something like `([a-zA-Z][a-z]+)+`?

The process could like this:
You get all the names to a file, there you automatically forge the replacement, and make (automatically) sed script to change one to another.